# From rational to integral generators of Néron–Severi group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, neron-severi-group

Suppose I've found rational generators for the Néron–Severi group $\mathrm{NS}(A)$ for an abelian
variety over $\mathbb{C}$. How would I check if they are integral generators for $\mathrm{NS}(A)$. Are there general methods?